# Trouble distinguishing meanings in verb past tense

Tags: tenses, past-tense

Imagine a map titled "Settlement 1904-1914".  In the key, red is labeled as "area that was settled during the time period".

From context, this seems like it means areas newly settled in the time period, not all areas that had the state of "being settled" during the time period (i.e. those which were settled previously and remained settled).  I do think it is ambiguous.

Is this actually ambiguous without contextual clues?  Or is there a verb tense I'm missing?

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide basic information about the historical period and the people or peoples concerned.

Comment: Yes, *was settled* could mean during that period, or by then.

Comment: @YosefBaskin *during* refers unequivocally to * from the beginning to the end of a particular period:* (Cambridge dictionary, for example) so there is no direct reference to the time preceding 1904. I suspect you commented more briefly than you intended. The reference to a past state of settlement is made by *settled*, and not by *during*.